# Auto index rebuild not happening in CD server (Sitecore 9.0 and Azure PaaS)

Tags: azure-search, paas

We have CM and CD servers in Azure PaaS, and Azure search service for indexing the items. After publishing the items from CM to CD auto index rebuild not happening.

Content Management index file configurations,

---

Content Delivery index file configurations,

```
<index id="demo_search_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure">
<param desc="name">$(id)</param>
<param desc="connectionStringName">cloud.search</param>
<param desc="totalParallelServices">5</param>
<!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
<param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration" />
<schemaBuilder ref="contentSearch/searchServiceSchemaBuilder" />
<searchService type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure" />
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
<!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance" />
</strategies>
<commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
<policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<Limit>1000</Limit>
</policy>
</policies>
</commitPolicyExecutor>
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<Database>web</Database>
<Root>/sitecore/content/Demo/Home</Root>
</crawler>
</locations>
</index>
```

Please suggest if any changes required for auto index rebuild?

Comment: Which version of 9.0 are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 9.0 update 2 (https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Commerce/90/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_90_Update2.aspx)

Comment: Try rebuilding the index and see if it is fixed afterwards. There is something tricky in 9.0.2 - am going to create a separete Q/A for that in a minute - and you might be facing that.

Comment: Check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/16324/237 - you might be having this one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set to `true` the setting `EnableEventQueues` in your `Sitecore.config`, and if not, create a patch and make it `true`.

[image]

The `OnPublishEndAsynch` strategy depends on this setting to work properly, because it will read the Events from the table `EventQueue` in the database you have defined. In your case `web`.

You can find more details in the official documentation for this strategy.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments Raul... Yeah updated  <setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true" /> section and after that created one item in CM and published to CD. When i search with that item it's not showing in search results page. Any thoughts? waiting for your response...

Comment: Make sure you set the setting on both CM and CD servers, so CM can insert events after publishing on the EventQueues table for CD to read it. Also check that this table has records after publishing, Sitecore compares the last time the index was updated with this records to trigger the re-index. Any errors captured on Application Insights?