# Azure Search SwitchOnRebuild returns no results

Tags: azure-search

I have created a separate publishing target (Production). I have created a separate index for this database (`sitecore_prod_index`).

I rebuild my index, and it returns results.

I rebuild again, no results. I can browse the index in azure and see that my results are there, but my code calling search does not return results.

I rebuild a third time and I get results.

Its like one of the rebuild indexes doesn't work, but the other does.

I'm performing a search like so:

```
using (var context = SiteSearchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var results = context.GetQueryable<MySearchResultModel>()
      .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(MyItemRoot.ID) && x.TemplateId == DetailPageConstants.TemplateId).GetResults();

    if (results.TotalSearchResults > 0)
    {
         return results.Hits.Select(q => q.Document).ToList();
    }

    return null;
}
```

SiteSearchContext is an `ISearchIndex` and it know which index to call (`sitecore_web_index` or `sitecore_prod_index`) based on a `appsettings` in the `web config`:

```
var searchIndexName = $"sitecore_{Context?.SitecoreService?.Database?.Name}_index";
var configuredIndexName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchIndexName"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configuredIndexName))
{
    searchIndexName = configuredIndexName;
}

SiteSearchIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(searchIndexName);
```

Comment: Have you followed these articles? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/zero-downtime-index-rebuild-in-azure-search.html and https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-azure-search.html

Comment: Yes, I have read these articles and applied the necessary configs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure if you have had the same issue as myself and Gatogordo but in 8.2 u7 and 9.02 there is a bug that prevents the active index name being updated correctly in the core db on CD servers. I've not got round to blogging about it but will do when I get a minute.

If this bug also exists with 9.1 you should be able to get a hotfix from support also.

You can read more info on this here: [Getting the primary Azure Search Index name after index re-build](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17792/getting-the-primary-azure-search-index-name-after-index-re-build)

The hotfix for 8.2.7 moved storage of the index name in use into an Azure index instead of the core db and this works fine.