# ERROR Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime

Tags: sxa, indexing, azure-search

We are receiving below errors during Indexing. We are on Sitecore 9 update-2, SXA 1.7.1 and using Azure search. The errors below seems related to SXA fields. Has anyone come across this issue?

```
10752 01:43:40 ERROR Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
   at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, DateTimeKind kind)
   at Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(String isoDate, DateTime defaultValue, Boolean treatLegacyDatesAsUtc)

8900 01:43:40 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: ispoi for indexable: sitecore://web/{37054431-C965-4FF5-B29A-9589C9DA06AE}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.Contains(ID fieldId)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.IsPoi.Verify(BaseItem item)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.IsPoi.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.c__DisplayClass55_0.b__0(IComputedIndexField computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)

6872 01:43:42 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: geolocation for indexable: sitecore://web/{D6F8E1E1-82E5-4E74-BD1D-F8508E44C33F}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.Contains(ID fieldId)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Azure.ComputedFields.AzureCoordinate.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.c__DisplayClass55_0.b__0(IComputedIndexField computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)

7340 01:43:43 ERROR Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
   at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, DateTimeKind kind)
   at Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(String isoDate, DateTime defaultValue, Boolean treatLegacyDatesAsUtc)

10948 01:43:43 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: ispoi for indexable: sitecore://web/{53EC4572-FCFE-4982-878F-7FDC369FB2AA}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.GetField(ID fieldID)
   at Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection.Contains(ID fieldId)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.IsPoi.Verify(BaseItem item)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.IsPoi.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.c__DisplayClass55_0.b__0(IComputedIndexField computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
```

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/sitecore-9-0-2-sxa-1-8-paas-azure-search-configuration

Comment: I highly recommend you upgrade to sxa 1.8.1 if you're on azure search

Comment: That is the first time I see such an error. Try to isolate the problem, narrow it to a single item. If you will do so, you will be able to check the field values of a single item which should be easy. Maybe you have a content issue, some kind of broken date/time value...